# Can ffmpeg report gaps in MPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, data-recovery

I have some MPEG-files with regular holes in them. Obviously, this makes the videos almost unwatchable, but `ffplay` tries and complains about lots of errors.

What it does not say, however, is the exact of playable chunks -- nor of the gaps between them. Can this information be extracted somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by gaps? Are these erroneous bitstreams with missing frames? Or missing packets? By MPEG, you mean MPEG-2 TS files?

Comment: Actual gaps in the file -- imagine hole of _K_ kilobytes appearing every _N_ kilobytes... I'd like to know the _K_ and the _N_...

Answer (score 2):

If by MPEG, you mean MPEG-2 Transport Streams, those have fixed packet sizes of 188 bytes. [Each packet starts with a sync byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#Elements) that is `0x47`.

By parsing the bitstream and looking for the positions of those bytes, you can get an idea which packets have been truncated (i.e. their length is < 188 bytes).

Of course, this does not work if more than one 188 bytes are lost at a time, or when the sync byte is lost. In that case, you have to additionally look at the continuity counter in every packet header you find. Some more info about the format is [here](https://tsduck.io/download/docs/mpegts-introduction.pdf).

But of course, this is just the MPEG-TS layer. A video slice or frame may stretch across multiple packets, so when a single packet of a frame is lost, you have to assume that the frame cannot be perfectly decoded (there may be chances for recovery). Also, it depends on the type of frame: lost I-frames will cause more damage (and thus render the stream unplayable) than lost P- or B-frames. That means you'll have to parse deeper into the bitstream.

If you really need to get detailed info on what is lost, probably the best way would be to debug/modify the FFmpeg TS demuxer and H.264 decoder (assuming H.264 video) to check where it fails, and print out some frame numbers/types while it's trying to decode.